# How can I determine why Visual Studio 2008 is hanging?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual studio is just hanging. The GUI just sits there and the CPU is at or near 0%.
I've let it sit for close to hour to see if it would resume, to no avail.

What is weird, is that the GUI doesn't respond to clicks anywhere, however, it re-draws correctly. If I drag another window over it, after the window passes over a portion, it is re-drawn correctly.

At the bottom of the VS window, it sometimes says 'Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after 5030 operations are completed', however, the GUI has hanged without it there.

I'm not sure if this is the cause or not.

I've tried /safemode, but I need the DB functionality loaded and using /safemode disables them.

I'm at a loss really.

More info -- The window stays as an unselected window even when I click on it. It's as though the whole thing is suspended except for the fact that it is redrawn properly when something else passes over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worthwhile to delete all of the temporary files (.ncb, etc.) that get created within your solution directory, and let VS re-create them. Sometimes they get corrupted.

The next thing I would do isto use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see if I can identify a thread that seems to be hanging, and whether it's in a particular module.

Comment: I already have ProcessExplorer -- How do you identify threads that are hanging?

Comment: If you double-click a process, you can get to a list of threads currently running. Double clicking on one of the threads gets its call stack.  Sometimes it's possible to identify that a particular thread is doing some task that isn't completing, or is in an infinite loop, or is stuck insine a 3rd party extension, for example. I'm not going to pretend that this is simple in any way. It's more of an art.... Mark Russinovich's blog has some examples where he's done some debugging this way, and he's more descriptive than I can be.